# Upload Textures to GPU

Tags: three.js

I have scene with several floors.

When user first time changed floor to another with different texture atlas (2048px * 8192px) I have micro freeze (I think at this time three.js upload needed texture atlas to gpu).

How can I upload material texture at init state and not wait at render time?

Comment: Use the TextureLoader().

Comment: Draw every texture once at startup